# Deploying JPA and REST packages separately in wildfly

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have created a JPA project as a jar and about to deploy in wildfly. I want to create a REST service as a seperate project and connect it to the JPA jar. I am not sure of how to do connectivity and secure them. I have tried googling and couldn't get help. Please provide guidelines and any links would be of much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Deploying JPA and REST packages separately, you have to use JPA project jar and inport into REST project. into REST project you have to write only controller and into to JPA project you have to write `Repo and services`. into REST project controler you can use JPA service.

Comment: Since i am deploying the JPA in wildfly how should i mention that dependency in maven for the REST project.